# Smarty PHP If No image

Tags: php, smarty

Hi can someone help me out please.

I'm using smarty engine and if there is no image how can i tell smarty or PHP to do something else for example.

I'm using this code

```
<div class="container_inner" style="background:url(/thumbs/backgrounds/movie_bg/{$mov.title|lower|replace:' ':'_'}.jpg)no-repeat center;">
```

To get different backgrounds for each movie page and if there is no image with the same movie title to do this instead.

```
<div class="container_inner">
```

Could someone please help me thanks.

Comment: You need to learn how to use PHP. You can use the function file_exists($file) to determine if the file in question exists and if not tell the page to use a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Smarty 3 you could do it this way

```
{assign "bgImg" "/thumbs/backgrounds/movie_bg/{$mov.title|lower|replace:' ':'_'}.jpg"}
{if file_exists($bgImg)}
    <div class="container_inner" style="background:url({$bgImg}) no-repeat center;">
{else}
    <div class="container_inner">
{/if}
```